# mv removed/lost files after moving to subfolder

Tags: mv

while working on my conky files I desided to put them neatly into a subfolder named `.conky`

these are the commands I ran:

```
$ ll .conk*
-rw-r--r-- 2  16K jan 28 12:09 .conkyrc
-rw-rw-rw- 1 6,7K jan 26 11:42 .conkyrc_bak
-rw-rw-rw- 1 7,0K jan 28 11:38 .conkyrc.conf_bak

.conky:
total 36K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 20K jan 28 11:49 conky_orange.lua
-rw-r--r-- 2 16K jan 28 12:09 conkyrc_orange_4k.conf

$ mv .conkyrc* .conky/

$ ll .conk*
total 36K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 20K jan 28 11:49 conky_orange.lua
-rw-r--r-- 2 16K jan 28 12:09 conkyrc_orange_4k.conf

$
```

as you can see the files that where sitting in my current directory are no longer there, nor in the folder I expected them to be.

can anybody shed some light on why they are not in the expected dir? and how I can recover at least the two `*_bak` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files are not lost.  They are in your `.conky` folder.  Their names are hidden (as they start with a dot).

When you first used `ll .conk*` you could see the files as they matched the pattern that you used (and you also saw the non-hidden names in the `.conky` directory, because that directory name also matched the pattern).  Then you moved the files and you did `ll .conk*` again.  This time the files are not in the current directory, but in `.conky`.  Since they are hidden and since their names don't match the pattern that you used (they are in a subdirectory), they are not shown.

You will see them if you do

```
ls -la .conky
```

You might have an alias already called something like `la` or `lla` or something similar that does `ls -la`.  If not, you can add that to your `.bashrc` file (or your shell's equivalent initialisation file for interactive shell sessions):

```
alias lla='ls -la'
```

Comment: thanks, I was under the impression that my `ll` alias had the `-a' option added to it... I was wrong, I have `la` for that and I forgot that. thanks for the quick reply